# Confusion Getting this Errorr Unable to get property 'checked' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In Function when i use .checked then it stop working & generate below Error.
Currently im using Visual Studio 2015.Please Help

```
function GenderValidation(sender , e)
    {
        var male = document.getElementById('RadioButton_male').Checked;
        var female = document.getElementById('RadioButton_female').Checked;
        if (male == true || female == true)
        {
            e.IsValid = true;
        } else {
            e.IsValid = false;
        }

    }
```

**

- **0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property
  'checked' of undefined or null reference**

**

**This is my Complete code**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="contactus.aspx.cs" Inherits="DVManagmentProject.contactus" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 70%;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            width: 190px;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            width: 190px;
            height: 34px;
        }
        .auto-style4 {
            height: 34px;
        }
        .auto-style5 {
            width: 190px;
            height: 150px;
        }
        .auto-style6 {
            height: 150px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"  >
        function GenderValidation(sender , e)
        {
            var male = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_RadioButton_male').Checked;
            var female = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_RadioButton_female').Checked;
            if (male == true || female == true)
            {
                e.IsValid = true;
            } else {
                e.IsValid = false;
            }

        }

        function CustomValidatorAgremennt(sender, e)
        {

            var agreemenT = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_CheckBox_agreement').Checked;
            if(agreemenT==true)
            {
                e.IsValid = true;
            }else
            {
                e.IsValid = false;
            }

        }
</script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <h2>
        This is Contact Us Page</h2>
                <asp:ValidationSummary ID="contact_ValidationSummary" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFF99" ForeColor="Black" Font-Bold="true" Width="694px" BorderStyle="Double" />
    <h3> Please Fill the Form Below:</h3>
    <br />
    <table class="auto-style1">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">Name:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="name_TextBox" runat="server" Width="320px"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_name" 
                    runat="server"  Text="*"
                    ErrorMessage="Please Enter Your Name" 
                    ForeColor="Red" 
                    ControlToValidate="name_TextBox" 
                    Display="Dynamic"
                     > </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                <%-- <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator_name" runat="server" 
                    ErrorMessage="*Text should between 10 to 30" MinimumValue="10" MaximumValue="30"
                    Type="Integer" ControlToValidate="name_TextBox"
                    Display="Dynamic"></asp:RangeValidator>--%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">Email:</td>
            <td class="auto-style4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="email_TextBox" runat="server" Width="320px"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_email" 
                    runat="server"  
                    SetFocusOnError="true"
                     Text="*" 
                    ErrorMessage="Please Enter Your Email Name" 
                    ControlToValidate="email_TextBox" 
                    ForeColor="Red" 
                    Display="Dynamic"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
                    ID="RegularExpressionValidator_email_TextBox" 
                    runat="server" 
                    ErrorMessage="Please Enter Correct Email Format"
                    Display="Dynamic"
                    ControlToValidate="email_TextBox"
                    ForeColor="Red"
                    SetFocusOnError="true"
                     Text="*"
                     ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" > </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">Re-Enter Email:</td>
            <td class="auto-style4">

                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_ReEmail" runat="server" Width="320px"></asp:TextBox>

                 <asp:CompareValidator 
                    ID="CompareValidator_ReEmail_TextBox" 
                    runat="server"
                    ErrorMessage="Email Must be Match"
                    Operator="Equal"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox_ReEmail"
                    ControlToCompare="email_TextBox"
                    Type="String"
                     Display="Dynamic"
                     ForeColor="Red"
                     Font-Bold="true">*</asp:CompareValidator>

                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_ReEmail" 
                    runat="server"  
                    SetFocusOnError="true"
                     Text="*" 
                    ErrorMessage="Please Confirm Your Email Name" 
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox_ReEmail" 
                    ForeColor="Red" 
                    Display="Dynamic"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
                    ID="RegularExpressionValidator_ReEmail" 
                    runat="server" 
                    ErrorMessage="Please Enter Correct Re-Email Format"
                    Display="Dynamic"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox_ReEmail"
                    ForeColor="Red"
                    SetFocusOnError="true"
                     Text="*"
                     ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">Gender:</td>
            <td class="auto-style4">

                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton_male" runat="server" Text="Male" GroupName="GenderGroup" />
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton_female" runat="server" Text="Female" GroupName="GenderGroup" />
                <asp:CustomValidator 
                    ID="CustomValidator_genders" 
                    runat="server" 
                    ErrorMessage="Please Select Gender.!" 
                    Font-Bold="True" 
                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator_genders_ServerValidate">*</asp:CustomValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">Age:</td>
            <td class="auto-style4">

                <asp:TextBox ID="Age_TextBox" runat="server" Width="318px"></asp:TextBox>

                   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
                    runat="server"  
                    SetFocusOnError="true"
                     Text="*" 
                    ErrorMessage="Please Enter Your Age" 
                    ControlToValidate="Age_TextBox" 
                    ForeColor="Red" 
                    Display="Dynamic"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                <asp:RangeValidator 
                    ID="RangeValidator_Age"
                    runat="server" 
                    ErrorMessage="Age should between 18 to 99"
                    Type="Integer"
                    Display="Dynamic"
                    SetFocusOnError="true"
                    ControlToValidate="Age_TextBox"
                    MinimumValue="18"
                    MaximumValue="99" 
                    ></asp:RangeValidator>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">Subject:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="subject_DropDownList" runat="server" Width="320px">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style5">Message </td>
            <td class="auto-style6">
                <asp:TextBox ID="message_TextBox" runat="server" Height="140px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="320px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">Agreement:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_agreement" runat="server" Text="Please Select Our Terms And Conditions.!" />
                    <asp:CustomValidator 
                        ID="CustomValidator_Agreement" 
                        runat="server" 
                        Display="Dynamic"
                        ErrorMessage="Please Check Terms and Conditions" 
                        Font-Bold="True" 
                        ForeColor="Red" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator_Agreement_ServerValidate">*</asp:CustomValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="submit_Button" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="Submit" Width="320px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
</asp:Content>
```

**This is Debbuger Code**

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG8hC.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqw0X.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuaNT.jpg
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrTPP.jpg
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Dhc1.jpg
  [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/880dI.jpg
  [7]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWQ7D.jpg
  [8]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdHXg.jpg
  [9]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVXI1.jpg
  [10]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC4LA.jpg
```

Comment: Can you also share the HTML code of radiobuttons? As per image `https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Dhc1.jpg` the radio button ids are `ContentPlaceHolder1_RadioButton_male` and `ContentPlaceHolder1_RadioButton_female`. You should use those ids in the javascript.

Comment: make sure you have a element with id `RadioButton_male` and `RadioButton_female` in your markup.

Comment: <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton_male" runat="server" Text="Male" GroupName="GenderGroup" />
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton_female" runat="server" Text="Female" GroupName="GenderGroup" />
                <asp:CustomValidator 
                    ID="CustomValidator_genders" 
                    runat="server" 
                    ErrorMessage="Please Select Gender.!" 
                    Font-Bold="True" 
                    ClientValidationFunction="GenderValidation" 
                    Display="Dynamic">*</asp:CustomValidator>

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Sir i used ContentPlaceHolder1_RadioButton_female,ContentPlaceHolder1_RadioButton_male code .it cant generate error right now but the problem is when i select radio button and click on Submit Button then the CustomValidator staric (*) and the Summary Error still be there.

Comment: what is CustomValidator? Where is Summary error? You need to share relevant code in your original question. Point out which code is giving error? what action you are performing in the UI which leads to the error? Sharing code via images is no recommended.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya kindly check my code .The problem is (.Checked) is not working in function (Javascript) and face this Error                       0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'checked' of undefined or null reference

Comment: You should be using all small letter `checked`.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thankyou so much u saved my time . my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is Solved . I have Changed

> ContentPlaceHolder1_RadioButton_male and
>   ContentPlaceHolder1_RadioButton_female

instead of

> RadioButton_male and RadioButton_female

as well as in Javascript Function .i have changed (.Checked) in small (.checked) and it worked for me .